# Could I use EventBus in Activities communication?

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

There are three activities  `A`, `B`, and `C`

1. Register `EventBus` in Activity A `onCreate()`,and unregister on `onDestroy()`, and a method  `onEvent(TestEvent e);`
2. Activity `A` starts Activity `B`
3. Activity `B` starts Activity `C`
4. In Activity `C`:

   ```java
   EventBus.getDefault().post(new TestEvent("close A"));
   ```

I use `EventBus` in this way , and it works well. Is there anything wrong in my code ?

Comment: If it works well, what is the purpose of the question?

Comment: my colleague said I can not use EventBus in this way ,And I am not sure use EventBus in this way is fine . Because of Activity life-cycle problem , I put the register in onCreate() and unregister in onDestroy().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay. EventBus is thread safe and has a lot of methods to make it easier to work with, like onEventMainThread, onEventBackgroundThread, onEventAsync.

The thing with your code is this: your activity will continue to get events even if it is in background. And that's okay (in this particular case). If, however, you'll have to implement something else in the future, keep this in mind:

- onCreate register -> onDestroy unregister
- onStart register -> onStop unregister
- onResume register -> onPause unregister

And there's something else, too: you have to make absolutely sure that your activity is only registered ONCE. Because, if you register more than once, you will receive as many events as the number of registers. Thus, please modify your register like this:

```
if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}
```

If you need more details, please read more about EventBus [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md).

However, if you follow these simple rules, your activity's lifecycle. I use it a lot and I don't encounter issues.